# Java Client-Server and Observer

Tags: java, client-server, observer-pattern

I am implementing a Java Client-Server application for a university task and I'm stuck at the following point: I am obliged to use client-server and also update the view whenever the data in the database changes. What I have done is that whenever a change in the database should occur I notify all the clients with the "CHANGE IN DATA" message and then the client should read and understand this message in order to call a method that will update it's graphic interface. However, or I'm mistaking the reading part on client side or because of some error, the clients don't read the "CHANGE IN DATA" message so the whole gets stuck at this point and the view doesn't update.

Here are some relevant codes!
Server class:

```
public class FinesPaymentServer implements Runnable {

private Database database;
private UserGateway userGateway;
private FineGateway fineGateway;
private DriverGateway driverGateway;
private Socket connection;
private int ID;
static ArrayList<Socket> clientsConnected;

/**
 * Constructor of the class connecting to the database and initializing the socket
 * @param database the database used
 * @param connection the socket for the server
 * @param ID the id
 */
private FinesPaymentServer(Database database, UserGateway userGateway, FineGateway fineGateway, DriverGateway driverGateway, Socket connection, int ID) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.userGateway = userGateway;
    this.fineGateway = fineGateway;
    this.driverGateway = driverGateway;
    this.database = database;
    this.ID = ID;
}

/**
 * Run method of the threads for each socket on the server
 */
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true)
            readFromClient(connection);
    } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    }
}

 /**
 * Read method from the client
 * @param client the client socket from where to read
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public void readFromClient(Socket client) throws IOException, SQLException {
    BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
    StringBuffer process = new StringBuffer();
    int character;
    while((character = reader.read()) != 13) {
        process.append((char)character);
    }
    System.out.println("[SERVER READ]: "+process);
    String[] words = process.toString().split("\\s+");
    switch (process.charAt(0)) {
        case 'a' : 
        {
            int type = database.verifyLogin(words[1], words[2]);
            sendMessage(client, ""+type + " ");
            break;
        }
        case 'b' :
        {
            String rs = userGateway.getUsers();
            sendMessage(client, rs);
            break;
        }
        case 'c' :
        {
            userGateway.createUser(words[1], words[2], words[3]);
            notifyClients();
            break;
        }
        case 'd' :
        {
            userGateway.updateUser(words[1], words[2], words[3]);
            notifyClients();
            break;
        }
        case 'e' :
        {
            userGateway.deleteUser(words[1]);
            notifyClients();
            break;
        }
    }
    try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e){}
    String time_stamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
    String returnCode = "Single Socket Server responded at " + time_stamp + (char) 13;
    sendMessage(client, returnCode);
}

/**
 * Method for sending messages from the server to the client
 * @param client the client socket where to send the message
 * @param message the message itself to be sent
 * @throws IOException 
 */
private void sendMessage(Socket client, String message) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write(message);
    System.out.println("[SERVER WRITE]: "+message);
    writer.flush();
}

public void notifyClients() throws IOException
{
    for(Socket s : clientsConnected)
    {
        sendMessage(s, "CHANGE IN DATA ");
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    Database database = new Database();
    UserGateway userGateway = new UserGateway();
    FineGateway fineGateway = new FineGateway();
    DriverGateway driverGateway = new DriverGateway();
    clientsConnected = new ArrayList<>();
    // Setting a default port number.
    int portNumber = 2015;
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println("Starting the multiple socket server at port: " + portNumber);
    try {
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    System.out.println("Multiple Socket Server Initialized");
    //Listen for clients
    while(true) {
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
    clientsConnected.add(client);
    Runnable runnable = new FinesPaymentServer(database, userGateway, fineGateway, driverGateway, client, ++count);
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
}
```

The client class:

```
public class FinesPaymentClient implements Runnable {

private String hostname = "localhost";
private int port = 2015;
Socket socketClient;
AdministratorModel adminModel;
PoliceModel policeModel;
PostModel postModel;

/**
 * Constructor of the class
 * @param hostname the host name of the connection
 * @param port the port of the connection
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public FinesPaymentClient(String hostname, int port, AdministratorModel adminModel, PoliceModel policeModel, PostModel postModel) throws UnknownHostException, IOException
{
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
    this.adminModel = adminModel;
    this.policeModel = policeModel;
    this.postModel = postModel;
    connect();
}

/**
 * Method for connecting to the host by a socket
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to " + hostname + ":" + port);
    socketClient = new Socket(hostname, port);
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}

/**
 * Method for reading response from the server
 * @return the string read from the server
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public String readResponse() throws IOException {
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println("[CLIENT READ]:");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
        return userInput;
    }
    return userInput;
}

/**
 * Method for closing connection between client and server
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void closeConnection() throws IOException {
    socketClient.close();
}

/**
 * Method for writing messages to the server
 * @param message the message to be sent
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public void writeMessage(String message) throws IOException {
    String time_stamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
    // Please note that we placed a char(13) at the end of process...
    // we use this to let the server know we are at the end
    // of the data we are sending
    String process = message + (char) 13;
    BufferedWriter stdOut = new BufferedWriter(
    new OutputStreamWriter(socketClient.getOutputStream()));
    stdOut.write(process);
    System.out.println("[CLIENT WRITE]: "+process);
    // We need to flush the buffer to ensure that the data will be written
    // across the socket in a timely manner
    stdOut.flush();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String response;
        while(true)
        {
            response = readResponse();
            System.out.println("HERE"+response.substring(0, 13));
            if(response.substring(0, 13).equals("CHANGE IN DATA"))
            {
                adminModel.setChange();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Main method of the application
 * @param arg the parameters given as arguments
 * @throws SQLException
 * @throws UnknownHostException
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String arg[]) throws SQLException, UnknownHostException, IOException {
    AdministratorModel adminModel = new AdministratorModel();
    PoliceModel policeModel = new PoliceModel();
    PostModel postModel = new PostModel();
    FinesPaymentClient client = new FinesPaymentClient("localhost", 2015, adminModel, policeModel, postModel);
    Runnable client2 = new FinesPaymentClient("localhost", 2015, adminModel, policeModel, postModel);
    Thread thread = new Thread(client2);
    thread.start();
    Login login = new Login();
    ClientSide clientSide = new ClientSide(login, client, adminModel, policeModel, postModel);
}
}
```

ClientSide class:

```
public class ClientSide {
private final Login login;
private FinesPaymentClient client;
AdministratorModel adminModel;
PoliceModel policeModel;
PostModel postModel;

/**
 * Constructor instantiating needed classes
 * @param login an instance of the login class
 * @param client the client needing the control logic
 * @param adminModel
 * @param policeModel
 * @param postModel
 * @throws SQLException using classes connecting to a database sql exceptions can occur
 */
public ClientSide(Login login, FinesPaymentClient client, AdministratorModel adminModel, PoliceModel policeModel, PostModel postModel) throws SQLException
{
    this.login = login;
    this.client = client;
    this.adminModel = adminModel;
    this.policeModel = policeModel;
    this.postModel = postModel;
    login.addButtonListener(new ButtonListener());
}

/**
 * Listener for the login button. Reads, verifies and provides the interface according to logged in user type.
 */
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        try 
        {
            client.writeMessage("a " + login.field1.getText()+ " " + login.field2.getText());
            String response = client.readResponse();
            if(response.charAt(0) == '1')
            {   
                login.setVisible(false);
                AdministratorGUI administratorGUI = new AdministratorGUI(adminModel, client);
                AdministratorController adminController = new AdministratorController(client, administratorGUI, adminModel);              
            }
            //if user is post office employee
            else if(response.charAt(0) == '2')
            {
                login.setVisible(false);
                PostGUI postGUI = new PostGUI();
                PostController postController = new PostController(client, postGUI, postModel);
            }
            //if user is police employee
            else if(response.charAt(0) == '3')
            {
                login.setVisible(false);
                PoliceGUI policeGUI = new PoliceGUI();
                PoliceController policeController = new PoliceController(client, policeGUI, policeModel);              
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Login failed! Please try again!");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException ex) 
        {
            Logger.getLogger(ClientSide.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm 99% sure that the error is on client side reading the message sent from the server as notification, but I simply cannot figure it out how could I retrieve that message. Right now I have a try in the client threads run method, but doesn't work. Other classes and other functionalities work just fine, this is my only problem. Do you have any ideas what the mistake could be? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Seems like you are starting a thread that does nothing. Thread thread = new Thread(), thread.start()

Comment: Yes, your are right. I edited the code in the main method of the client class, but the same problem is still up.

Comment: ClientSide is my controller for login. I will post it right know, but there is no problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

for my solution I needed a list of all connected clients on server-side:

```
public class ClientListModel {
    private List<ClientHandler> liste = new LinkedList<>();
    private ClientListView clientView;

    public List<ClientHandler> getListe() {
        return liste;
    }

    public void setListe(List<ClientHandler> liste) {
        this.liste = liste;
    }

    public ClientListView getClientView() {
        return clientView;
    }

    public void setClientView(ClientListView clientView) {
        this.clientView = clientView;
    }

    public void update() {
        clientView.update();
    }

    public void add(ClientHandler echoClientHandler) {
        liste.add(echoClientHandler);
        update();
    }

    public void remove(ClientHandler echoClientHandler) {
        liste.remove(echoClientHandler);
        update();
    }
}
```

The view-class prints out information to the console:

```
public class ClientListView {
    ClientListModel clientModel;

    public ClientListView() {
        super();
    }

    public void update() {
        System.out.println("*** connected clients ***");
        for (ClientHandler client : clientModel.getListe()) {
            System.out.println(client.getClientSocket().getInetAddress());
        }
    }

    public ClientListModel getClientModel() {
        return clientModel;
    }

    public void setClientModel(ClientListModel clientModel) {
        this.clientModel = clientModel;
    }
}
```

The actual server holds both classes. It can send a update trigger to all registered client handlers.

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private int port;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private ClientListModel clientListModel = new ClientListModel();
    private ClientListView clientListView = new ClientListView();
    private PostgresMock postgres;

    public Server(int port) {
        this.port = port;
        this.postgres = new PostgresMock("me", "pass123");

        // initiate mvc
        getClientListModel().setClientView(clientListView);
        clientListView.setClientModel(getClientListModel());

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("listening on port " + port);
            while (true) {
                new ClientHandler(serverSocket.accept(), this);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }

    public void updateClients() {
        for (ClientHandler client : getClientListModel().getListe()) {
            client.sendMsg("trigger update");
        }
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        this.serverSocket.close();
    }

    public ClientListModel getClientListModel() {
        return clientListModel;
    }

    public PostgresMock getPostgres() {
        return postgres;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(5555);
    }

}
```

Here is the client handler:

```
public class ClientHandler implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private Server server;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket, Server server) {
        this.clientSocket = socket;
        this.server = server;
        server.getClientListModel().add(this);

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                
                // IN
                System.out.println("in: " + inputLine);
                
                JSONArray data = server.getPostgres().execute(inputLine);
                
                if (!isSelectStatement(inputLine)) {
                    server.updateClients();
                }
                if (data == null) {
                    sendMsg("nil");
                    continue;
                }
                
                sendMsg(data.toString());
                
                // OUT
                System.out.println("out: " + data.toString());
                
            }
            server.getClientListModel().remove(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            server.getClientListModel().remove(this);
        } 
    }

    public Socket getClientSocket() {
        return clientSocket;
    }

    private boolean isSelectStatement(String sql) {
        return sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("SELECT") || sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("WITH");
    }

    public void sendMsg(String msg) {
        out.println(msg);
    }

}
```

It detects whether a select statement or a some other statement is going to be executet. If its not a select statement the server will trigger updates.

The Postgres class is just a mock class.

```
public class PostgresMock {

    public PostgresMock(String user, String password) {

    }

    public JSONArray execute(String sqlStatement) {
        return new JSONArray();
    }
}
```

Finally the client class. It does a lot of stuff but most importently it triggers the actual update method.

```
public class Client implements Runnable {
    private volatile String msgOut = null;
    private volatile String msgIn = null;
    private volatile boolean done = true;
    private int queryTimeout = 1000;

    private Socket clientSocket;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    private String ip;
    private int port;

    private Thread t;

    private static volatile boolean active = true;

    private static int clockRate = 1;

    public Client(String ip, int port) {
        this.ip = ip;
        this.port = port;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            connect();

            String response;

            while (active) {

                if (getMsgOut() != null) {
                    out.println(getMsgOut());
                    setMsgOut(null);
                }

                response = readResponse();

                if (response != null) {
                    System.out.println(java.time.LocalDateTime.now() + ": in: " + response);
                }

                pollResponse(response);

                // slow down loop
                Thread.sleep(clockRate);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void connect() {
        while (clientSocket == null && active) {
            try {
                clientSocket = new Socket(ip, port);
                out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String readResponse() throws IOException {
        String userInput = null;
        while (in.ready() && (userInput = in.readLine()) != null) {
            return userInput;
        }
        return userInput;
    }

    private void pollResponse(String response) {
        if (response == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (response.equals("trigger update")) {
            System.out.println("do update stuff here ..."); // trigger your update event here
        } else {
            setMsgIn(response);
        }
    }

    public String query(String sql, long timeout) {
        while (!done) {} // I don't know if this is actually necessary

        done = false;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        setMsgIn(null);
        setMsgOut(sql);

        while ((System.currentTimeMillis() - start < timeout) && getMsgIn() == null) {}
        
        setMsgOut(null);

        done = true;

        return getMsgIn();
    }

    public String query(String sql) {
        return query(sql, queryTimeout);
    }

    String getMsgOut() {
        return msgOut;
    }

    void setMsgOut(String msgOut) {
        this.msgOut = msgOut;
    }

    String getMsgIn() {
        return msgIn;
    }

    void setMsgIn(String msgIn) {
        this.msgIn = msgIn;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client c = new Client("127.0.0.1", 5555);
        c.query("select * from atable;");
        c.query("insert into atable (avalue) values ('anything');");
    }

}
```

I didn't do a lot of optimization to the code but I hope it helps.